ROS2 cannot find "base_link"
I am trying to transform points from the camera coordinate frame to the base coordinate frame in ROS 2. Here’s my code:
import tf2_ros
import rclpy
from tf2_geometry_msgs import do_transform_point
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point

rclpy.init()
node = rclpy.create_node('transform_debug')

tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=1.0))
tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer, node)

# Transform point coordinates to the target frame.
source_frame = 'camera_depth_frame'
target_frame = 'base_link'

# get the transformation from source_frame to target_frame.
transformation = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame,
            source_frame, rclpy.time.Time(), rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=0.1))

point_source = Point(x=0.1, y=1.2, z=2.3)
point_target = do_transform_point(transformation, point_source)

When I run this with:
ros2 launch stretch_core stretch_driver.launch.py

The code results in the following error:
transformation = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame,source_frame, rclpy.time.Time(), rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=3.0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf2_ros/buffer.py", line 136, in lookup_transform
    return self.lookup_transform_core(target_frame, source_frame, time)
tf2.LookupException: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist

Any idea why ROS 2 cannot seem to find “base_link”, when this worked perfectly fine in ROS 1?

Can you please add a screenshot of the frames tree? You can get it using the command ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames

Assuming the frames are correctly published by some other nodes, try to add a little sleep after creating the listener.
I had the same problem where the listener would work correctly only after some time from its initialization.
Then in the future, when you want other transforms, you should use the same listener without creating a new one and it works correctly
